# View bound to ViewModel does not contain a definition for some objects

Tags: asp.net

I have a View bound to a ViewModel containing Products and Contacts. I display 
the Products in one part of the View and that works. I need to expose the data 
definition for Contacts so I can 
take input and Post to the Contacts model.

It fails first at this line 
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactFName)

Error message:
'ProductPageViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ContactFName'

PRODUCTPAGEVIEWMODEL.CS

```
public class ProductPageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Products> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public string VmMessage { get; set; }
}
```

PRODUCTS CONTROLLER , INDEX ACTION

```
public ActionResult Index(string product)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(product))
    {
        product = "homepage";
    }
    var products = db.DbProducts.Where(m => m.Category == product);
    var contacts = db.DbContacts;

     var model = new ViewModel.ProductPageViewModel
    {
        Contacts = contacts,
        Products = products,
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

PRODUCTS MODEL

```
public class Products 
{
    [Key]
    public int WpId { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ProdDescShort { get; set; }
    public string ProdDescLong { get; set; }
    public string ProductSmall { get; set; }
    public string ProductMedium { get; set; }
    public string ProductLarge { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price1 { get; set; }
 }
```

CONTACTS MODEL

```
public class Contact
{   
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }
    public string ContactFName { get; set; }
    public string ContactLName { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string ContactComments { get; set; }        
    public string ContactBirthday { get; set; }
    public string ContactSource { get; set; }
}
```

INDEX VIEW

```
@model JaniesWebLive.ViewModel.ProductPageViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddItem", "Carts"))
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Products)
    {
        <p><img class="product-image" src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductMedium) /></p>
        <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WpProductId)</h3>
        <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price1)</h5>
        <h6>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdDescShort)</h6>
        <p class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdDescLong)</p>
        <p>
            <button class="text-right btn btn-link js-delete">ADD TO CART</button>
        </p>
    }
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitContact", "Products"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactFName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactFName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactLName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactLName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactEmail)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactComments)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ContactComments, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 3 })
    </div>
    @Html.Hidden("ContactSource", "DealsSignup")
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in PRODUCTS CONTROLLER , INDEX ACTION
Try:
var contacts = db.DbContacts**.Tolist();**

or even in viewModel initialisation you can put already:

Contacts = db.DbContacts**.Tolist();**

You are passing concrete product but set of contacts.

> ```
> var products = db.DbProducts.Where(m => m.Category == product);
>
>  var model = new ViewModel.ProductPageViewModel
> {
>     Contacts = db.DbContacts.ToList(),
>     Products = products
> };
> return View(model); }
> ```